# What are some of the most ridiculous claims in computer science that we haven't disproved?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

What are some of the most ridiculous possible claims in computer science that we haven't disproved?
E.g. For example the claim that ZPP=exptime is absurd but has not been disproven.

Comment: See [List of unsolved problems in computer science](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science).

Comment: None of those are "absurd"

Comment: So say you.  Claim:  There exists one-way functions (absurd!).  Claim: The polynomial hierarchy is finitely high (absurd!).

Comment: What makes _ZPP=exptime_ absurd?

Comment: It asserts that random data (formally, all but an exponentially small percentage of strings) are in fact a vast store wisdom allowing us to solve exponential time complete problems in polynomial time.  Unsuitable strings passed as random may be rejected but will not lead to mistakes.